# convert Observable of Observables to simple Observable

Tags: rxjs

I am using Rxjs and things looks good so far! I have this problem

how can I achieve this?

```
  // I have observable of observables!
    const bad$ = Rx.Observable.of([
      Rx.Observable.of(1),
      Rx.Observable.of(2),
      Rx.Observable.of(3),
      Rx.Observable.of(4),
      Rx.Observable.of(5)
    ])

    // I want to convert it to something like this
    const good$ = Rx.Observable.of([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Comment: Use `concatAll()`, `mergeAll()`, `concatMap(o => o)` or `mergeMap(o => o)`. For example: `bad$.concatAll()`

Comment: this did the trick!

Comment: @martin can you make this an answer and use it in an example?

Answer (score 1):

As @martin already commented, the easy way to convert Observable of Observables to simple Observable with all emitted values is to use `concatAll` operator, i.e.:

```
const good$ = bad$.concatAll()
```